# I am trying to install nginx in Ubuntu 16.04, but I get an error about locale settings

Tags: node.js, reactjs, shell, ubuntu, nginx

I am trying to install nginx on my Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) on [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy), but I am getting locale setting errors.

I have a full MongoDB Express React Node.js project with [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). I deployed this project before I added the REST API with [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)). The project didn't work correctly because nginx.conf was wrong (possibly, it could've been somewhere else, but the error was post method (405)).

So I wanted to re-deploy the project since I found a [article](https://medium.com/@rksmith369/how-to-deploy-mern-stack-app-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-nginx-the-right-way-e76c1a8cd6c6) for deploying a [MERN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack) project correctly.

I just wanted a fresh start....

This is the error I get when I try to install nginx on Ubuntu with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential openssl libssl-dev pkg-config
```

I tried other answers that I got from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015398/cant-set-locales-ubuntu-16-04), but they didn’t work. Like typing a bunch of commands into Ubuntu.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015398/cant-set-locales-ubuntu-16-04

etc...

This the error get:

```
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
(Reading database ... 36967 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing nginx-common (1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
Purging configuration files for nginx-common (1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Setting up postfix (3.1.0-3ubuntu0.3) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

But if i continue deploying regardless of above error, I get this:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-01-08 21:14:31 MST; 23ms ago
  Process: 18459 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 08 21:14:31 s166-62-124-233.secureserver.net nginx[18459]: nginx: [emerg] socket() [::]:80 failed ...l)
Jan 08 21:14:31 s166-62-124-233.secureserver.net nginx[18459]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/ng...ed
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) | nginx-full (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) | nginx-light (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3) | nginx-extras (>= 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-core
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$
```

When I deployed my project without nginx installed:

[Screenshot of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6y3f.png)

Comment: I had the same locale errors on all the vps that I tried before.
but i think locale (lang) errors do not have conflicts with nginx. you can ignore these messages. only take advice and care of the others.

Comment: I pretty sure i need to run this command `sudo service nginx reload && sudo service nginx restart` when i do this command i get **nginx.service is not active, cannot reload**.

Comment: I usually installed nginx the way vishal singh answer. 
if youre trying to start service after installation and the error occurs, maybe you need to upate ubuntu and reinstall nginx; so if you already configured nginx you can use `nginx -t` to test the config.

Comment: `$ nginx -t
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2019/01/08 23:28:47 [warn] 22960#22960: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
2019/01/08 23:28:47 [emerg] 22960#22960: directive "proxy_pass" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/LCTW:4
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed`
This is the error I get. how do you update ubuntu? Is there fully reset?

Comment: try the command like superuser > `sudo nginx -t`

Comment: for "update ubuntu" i refer to update the repositores > `sudo apt-get update`
after that try reinstalling nginx, if everything still the same then remove and purge nginx > `sudo apt-get remove --purge nginx` and upgrade ubuntu 
`sudo apt-get upgrade` and install nginx again.

Comment: seems like a missed semicolon in some sites-enabled config file.
"`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1 2019/01/08 23:28:47 [emerg] 22960#22960: directive "proxy_pass" is not terminated by ";" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/LCTW:4 `"

Comment: Ok Thank you, so i just ignore the locale errors and continue to deploy. I still wasn't able to install nginx...
Same errors as above on actual post.
When I go visit the site i get "Ubuntu Logo Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page
It works!" 
I will edit the actual post with screen shot of the page.

Comment: if you run apache2 service before nginx then apache2 "owns" the 80 port. and you are not able to run nginx server because try to run in default 80 port.. 
try stoping apache2 service 
> `sudo service apache2 stop`
and then start nginx service.. 

or specify a diferent port in nginx or apache2 ports config files.

Comment: [ here is some methods to solve or evade the local errors. ](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/os-x-terminal-bash-warning-setlocale-lc_ctype-cannot-change-locale/)

Comment: Thank you its working now. i think it had two port 80. got rid of one and works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run Apache 2 service before nginx, both with the default port configuration, then Apache 2 is using the 80 port and you are not able to start the nginx server, because it is trying to run on the same default 80 port.

Try stopping the Apache 2 service → `sudo service apache2 stop` and then start the nginx service → `sudo service nginx start`, or specify a different port in the nginx or Apache ports configuration files for using both servers simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

instead of including `git -y` in the command. It's quite simple, and you didn't have to do that as it finds Git on your server or locally which is a dependency.